# How to contact the Mexican Consulate in Boston?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, mexico, consulates, boston

We need to contact them about a Visa issue. The security guard won't let you in without an appointment but they do not pick up the phone, they don't return messages and all e-mail remains unanswered so we can't get an appointment. We've been trying since two weeks without any luck whatsoever

Has anyone seen this before? Any idea on how to proceed here?

UPDATE: we called the consulate in New York: They picked up on the first try and were very helpful. Go figure. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Tweet to https://twitter.com/ConsulmexBoston ?

Comment: If memory serves, the Mexican consulate in Kansas City keeps pretty limited hours (at least for answering the phone). I had some trouble (but not as bad as yours) contacting them about 3 years ago, when I was getting a visa. Have you tried calling at different times of day? You might also try calling one of the other consulates and explain your situation. I'm sure they won't be able to help you directly, but they might have some other way to rouse the attention of the Boston consulate.  Then again, they may not be able to help, but all you'll lose is some time on the phone.

Comment: I never had a problem. I just walked in off the street the first time. For the second appointment they answered the phone right away and it only took a few minutes to make the appointment. (Nov. 2016)

Answer (score 2):

[The contact details for the Mexican Consulate in Boston](http://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/boston/index.php/en/consulado) are below (screenshot from their website):

[image: Mexican Consulate Boston]

If you are having bad luck contacting them you still have several alternative options:

1. Contact another consulate close-by, informing them about your problem with the Boston one and asking for their help.
2. [Tweet the Mexican Consulate in Boston](https://twitter.com/ConsulmexBoston) for help.